# Python: Using heap commands on a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, binary-heap

I'm trying to understand some of Python's built in heap functionality. It seems to not like things when I pass in a list of tuples (or more likely, I'm not passing the list in correctly). Here is what I have:

```
myList = ( ('a', 1), ('b', 2) )
heapify(myList)
```

The error that I get is

> TypeError: heap argument must be a list

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to pass in a list of tuples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `myList` is a tuple. Try this:

```
myList = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
heapify(myList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, lazyr. It's easy for someone new to the language to miss something like that. Something that Ber might want to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

As above heapify transforms a list (myList) into a heap. So if you want to use heapify you must translate everything to a list first.

http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html <--- Gives you a bit more detail about heapq

Comment: Thanks. I am using this as a reference to learn about binary heaps, but I just overlooked the fact that my data structure was instantiated as a tuple when I meant to create it as a list.